# How to load java native library in web container

Tags: java, tomcat, java-native-interface, jetty, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm migrating a Java application which uses a proprietary native library from standalone to web base, it works fine when running at the command line or in eclipse but throws UnsatisfiedLinkError when calling native methods inside the web container.

I have managed to load other different native libraries in the web application, and neither System.load nor System.loadLibrary throws any error. I added some logs in my application after loading each library to verify this.

I have though it could be an issue with the web container so I tried to use Jetty and Tomcat, but I'm getting the same error in both.

Currently using:
 - Java 1.8.0_72
 - Jetty 9.3.6
 - Tomcat 8.0.30
 - Debian 8
 - Gcc 4.9.2

To illustrate a bit more I have two native libraries in exactly the same directory and both .so files have the same permissions. One of them throws the error while the other just works, if I remove the .so file for the one that is failing I got:
`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no proprietary-lib in java.library.path`

Looks like there is something in my library that the web container doesn't like, What could it be?

Comment: Well, where did you place your native library?

Comment: is there a stacktrace you can include in the question?

Comment: The stacktrace is not very helpful it seems like if the library hasn't been loaded at all, its a very simple:
`Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: test.Test.nativeMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)J`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JNI correctly with Java EE (Servlets) on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413399/how-to-use-jni-correctly-with-java-ee-servlets-on-windows)